# Why Debye shielding occur in plasma?

Tags: electrons, charge, plasma-physics, ions, debye-length

Why Debye shielding occur in plasma
when we introduce a test charge?
Does Debye shielding depends on test charge
When it is introduced in plasma?

Answer (score 0):

> Why Debye shielding occur in plasma when we introduce a test charge?

The short answer is that electric fields do work to get rid of themselves.

> Does Debye shielding depends on test charge When it is introduced in plasma?

I am not sure what you are asking here but [Debye shielding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debye_length) occurs in a [plasma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_(physics)) because the charges are free to move and electric fields do work to get rid of themselves.